# Yii2: behavior as array (not work) or as attachBehavior (work)

Tags: yii2, behavior, attachedbehaviors

I have such class i get object in function **actionCreate**:

```
use app\components\ModelHelperBehavior;

class UserController extends Controller{

   public function actionCreate(){

            $model = new User();
            $model->attachBehavior(HelperBehavior::className());
            var_dump($model->getBehaviors());
        }
    }
}
```

But if i use this code- i get null

```
use app\components\ModelHelperBehavior;

class UserController extends Controller{

    public function behaviors(){
        return [
            HelperBehavior::className(),
            ],
        ];
    }
   public function actionCreate(){

            $model = new User();
            var_dump($model->getBehaviors());
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: how can i attach behavior to UserInfo in the second code example using an array?

P.S. My behavior code is:

```
class HelperBehavior extends Behavior{

    public function getGigit() {
          return 111;
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated. Here yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html i found the example "You may also attach behaviors through configurations like the following: " but how can i write it in my example? –

Answer (score 1):

You should add:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        HelperBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

to `UserInfo` class, not controller.

Comment: Ok i changed UserInfo() to User() but the same problem

Comment: How would change class name solve the problem?
I've written that you have `behaviors()` method in wrong class. Not that class name is wrong...

Comment: No, look the example- behavior is in the right class now (after renaming): behavior array is in User class. Here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html i found exaple "You may also attach behaviors through configurations like the following: " but how can i write it in my example?

Comment: You should not manually attach it in this case. Just add it to your model behaviors, not to controller.

Comment: Yeah- add behavior using function behaviors() could be only in model class and not controller. ty